# How to perform a simple smoothing forecast for next 12 months (using forecast package in R)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I currently have timeseries data (of gold prices) and I am trying to use a simple smoothing forecast to estimate gold prices for the next 12 months.

I am not sure what function to use to accomplish this ( I am pretty new to R)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `forecast` package, its functions and their use, and indeed, the basics of forecasting more generally are discussed in the online text [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp). In particular, see the functions [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/a). There are a number of functions you *might* use. As it stands your question seems to be too broad and unfocused (and if it's only asking 'what function do I call', may also be closed as off-topic)

Comment: Indeed that second link above lists 12 functions that produce a forecast object.

Comment: Thanks! that helps. How do you know what alpha the methods are using?

Comment: alpha? What's alpha? Are you talking about *exponential smoothing* perhaps? Please be explicit about what you mean by alpha.

Comment: Yes I am sorry about being vague, I am very new to stat. I guess the question should ask "how to perform a simple exponential smoothing forecast"

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The function `ses` in `forecast` performs simple exponential smoothing.

The function takes an `alpha` parameter (i.e. you can tell it what alpha you want). If you don't specify one it estimates it, and it will be in the output if you call `summary` on the returned object.

For details on exponential smoothing and examples of how to use the function, see sec 7.1 of the book by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/1)

[1] Hyndman, R.J., Athanasopoulos (2012),
  "Forecasting: principles and practice",
  OTexts: Melbourne, Australia.
  http://otexts.com/fpp.